# Are two similar matrices A and B unique?

Tags: linear-algebra

Are two similar matrices A and B unique? As in if A is similar to B, is it similar to B and itself only?

Comment: You are aware that every square matrix is similar to itself?

Comment: Similar matrices have identical rational forms. As for your question, A when it is a square is similar to itself and to its transpose!

Comment: Most square matrices $A$ have an infinite number of matrices $B$ to which they are similar.  However when $A$ is a *scalar matrix* (scalar multiple of the identity), it does happen that $A$ is similar only to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not even almost. Most matrices are even similar to infinitely many other matrices. An example is a matrix with the numbers $1,2,3,...,n$ on the diagonal, and zeros everywhere else. This matrix is similar to all of the other matrices with any permutation of $1,2,3,...,n$ on their diagonal.

The only matrices which are similar to only one matrix are matrices which are scalar multiples of the identity. They are similar only to themselves.

Answer (score 1):

No. If A is a square matrix that is not necessarily symmetric, then $A$ is similar both to $A$ and $A^{T}$.

Answer (score 0):

We say matrix $A$ is similar to matrix$B$ if there exists a non singular matrix $P$ such that $A=P^{-1}AP$. Form the very defnition it is clear that matrix $B$ is not unique.
However, the relation of similarty in matrices is an eqvivalence relation. Matrices $ A,B$ and $P$ are square matrices.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is a square matrix that is not a multiple of the identity $I$, there is some square matrix $B$ that it fails to commute with: $AB \ne BA$.  Then also $A (I + tB) \ne (I+tB) A$, and $(I+tB)^{-1} A (I+tB)$ (when $I + t B$ is invertible) is a matrix similar to $A$ that is not $A$.  Moreover, since the entries of $(I+tB)^{-1} A (I+tB)$ are rational functions of $t$ and not all constant, we find that $A$ is similar to infinitely many different matrices.